# How do I print a nested input in a function in another function

Tags: python

I working on a booking system. And after the user chooses which type of vehicle he want's, it will print the details of the vehicle from the list when executed in (def availabilty():).

But the problem arises when I need the details to be brought over and printed to the next function (def reservations():) And since the input printed is fix due to the (if choice_avail == "1c":), I'm unable to bring the vehicles details atomically over to print it out under the (def reservations():).

```
def availabilty():
    print()
    print("******* Vehicle Availabilty *******")

    choice_avail = input("""
                        1c , 2c , 3c , 4c , 5c, 6c,
                        Please Enter the following Choices:""")
    
if choice_avail == "1c":
    print("You have selected the following Model.")
    print(table_car[1])
    reservations()
    
elif choice_avail == "2c":
    print("You have selected the following Model.")
    print(table_car[2])
    reservations()
    
elif choice_avail == "3c":
    print("You have selected the following Model.")
    print(table_car[3])
    reservations()
    
elif choice_avail == "4c":
    print("You have selected the following Model.")
    print(table_car[4])
    reservations()

elif choice_avail == "5c":
    print("You have selected the following Model.")
    print(table_car[5])
    reservations()

elif choice_avail == "6c":
    print("You have selected the following Model.")
    print(table_car[6])
    reservations()
    
else:
    print(" ------------ Invalid Choice, Please Choose Again! ------------------")
    vehicletype()

def reservations():
    print()
    print()
    print("******* Reservations *******")
    user_name = input('Your Name is:')
    user_age =  input ('Your Age is:')
    user_gender = input('Your Gender is (M/F):')
    user_adress = input('Your adress is:')
    user_collection_date = input('Your collection date is (DD/MM/YYYY):')
    user_collection_time  = input('Your collection time is (AM/PM):')
    user_contact = input('Your contact number is:')
    print()
    print()
    print("*** You have provide the following details.***\n Name : {} \n Age : {} \n Sex : {} \n Adress : {} \n Date : {} \n Time : {} \n Contact : {}"
          .format(user_name, user_age, user_gender, user_adress, user_collection_date, user_collection_time, user_contact ))
    again()
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right...

Just pass the information into reservations, something like so (reduced as I'm rushing!)

```
def availabilty():
    print()
    print("******* Vehicle Availabilty *******")

    choice_avail = input("""
                        1c , 2c , 3c , 4c , 5c, 6c,
                        Please Enter the following Choices:""")

if choice_avail == "1c":
    print("You have selected the following Model.")
    print(table_car[1])
    reservations(choice_avail)


def reservations(choice_avail):
    
    tabCar = table_car[int(choice_avail[:1])]  #This is the sub list ['1c', 'Chevorlet Camaro', '30 mpg', 4, 2, 'WGB...']

    print()
    print()
    print("******* Reservations *******")
    user_name = input('Your Name is:')
    user_age =  input ('Your Age is:')
    user_gender = input('Your Gender is (M/F):')
    user_adress = input('Your adress is:')
    user_collection_date = input('Your collection date is (DD/MM/YYYY):')
    user_collection_time  = input('Your collection time is (AM/PM):')
    user_contact = input('Your contact number is:')
    print()
    print()
    print("*** You have provide the following details.***\n Name : {} \n Age : 
{} \n Sex : {} \n Adress : {} \n Date : {} \n Time : {} \n Contact : {}"
          .format(user_name, user_age, user_gender, user_adress, 
user_collection_date, user_collection_time, user_contact ))
    again()
```

Comment: OMG!! I love you, you have resolve my 3 days worth of pain. :)